# Power series solution of differential equation $y'=x^2 +y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

so I'm working to find a power series solution for diffrential equation : $y'(x)=x^2 + y(x)$ with given $y(0)=1$ and

[image: given]

and i have to prove that the power serie is a solution to this equation.
i did that and eventually found that the relation:

[image: relation]

(which is correct because it's given in the question as a hint)

and after that the question is to find what $a_n$ equals to .
so after my calculations i found somthing like this

[image: answer]

my question is can add them together, and if I made a mistake in anything please correct me.

Comment: I generalized this to an arbitrary polynomial in place of $x^2$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456598/what-is-the-solution-to-y-pxy-where-px-sum-k-0d-p-kxk. At the end of that I rederived the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the series in your answer is correct, but what is the question?

If you want an abbreviation here is one
$$
1+x+\frac12（x^2+x^3）+\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{3}{k!} x^k
\\=3\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} x^k-3(1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3)+1+x+\frac12（x^2+x^3）\\
=3 \exp(x)-2-2x-x^2
$$