# What is the solution to $y'=p(x)+y $ where $p(x) =\sum_{k=0}^d p_kx^k $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

This is a generalization of
[Power series solution of differential equation $y'=x^2 +y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456540/power-series-solution-of-differential-equation-y-x2-y)

> Show that the solution to
> $y'=p(x)+y$
> where
> $p(x) =\sum_{k=0}^d p_k x^k$
> is
> $$
> y(x) =ce^x- \sum_{j=0}^d \frac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! 
> $$
> where
> $c=y(0)+\sum_{k=0}^d p_kk!$.

Here is my solution.

$$
\begin{split}
p(x) &= y'-y \quad \text{so}\\
e^{-x}p(x) &= e^{-x}(y'-y) = (ye^{-x})' \quad \text{so} \\
ye^{-x} &= \int p(x)e^{-x} dx =\sum_{k=0}^d p_k\int x^ke^{-x} dx
\end{split}
$$
or
$$y =e^x\sum_{k=0}^d p_k\int x^ke^{-x} dx.$$

Since

$$\begin{split}
\int x^ke^{-x} dx
&=-e^{-x}x^k\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(k-i)}{x^j}\\
&=-e^{-x}x^k\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{k!}{(k-j)!x^j}\\
&=-e^{-x}x^kk!\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{1}{j!x^{k-j}}\\
&=-e^{-x}k!\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{x^j}{j!}\\
\end{split}
$$

$$
\begin{split}
y
&=e^x\sum_{k=0}^d p_k\int x^ke^{-x} dx\\
&=-e^x\sum_{k=0}^d p_ke^{-x}k!\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{x^j}{j!}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^d p_kk!\sum_{j=0}^{k} \dfrac{x^j}{j!}\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{d}\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! \dfrac{x^j}{j!}\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^{d}\dfrac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! \\
\end{split}
$$

To be correct,
as some of you have
probably noticed,
we need a constant of integration
$c$
which will add
$ce^x$
to this sum,
so
$y(x)
=ce^x-\sum_{j=0}^{d}\dfrac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! 
$.

To get $c$,
put $x=0$ so
$y(0)
=c-\sum_{k=0}^d p_kk! 
$
or
$c
=y(0)+\sum_{k=0}^d p_kk! 
$.

In the problem
which inspired this,
$y(0)=1$ and
$p(x)=x^2$
so $c=1+2=3
$.
Also
$\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! 
=2
$
so

$$\sum_{j=0}^{d}\dfrac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^d p_kk! =2+2x+x^2$$

Comment: Great generalization! Is there some question i can help with?

Comment: Nah. This is another case when I have derived a result and am unsure of the best way to present it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I suggest that your "question" should contain a question. Moreover, I suggest that question should be in the body of the question, rather than in a comment on the question.

Comment: You asked for suggestions, marty. I gave you two. You're ignoring them. Come on, marty. Meet me halfway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to solve
$y'=y+x^n$ for any $n,$ multiply by constants, and add up results. The homogeneous equation $y'=y$ admits solutions of the form $ce^{x}.$ Next we should look for a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation. The power series expansion of the equation $(e^x)'=e^x$ gives
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^k\over k!}\right )'=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^k\over k!}$$
So it is natural to look what happens to the partial sums $s_n(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {x^k\over k!}.$ We immediately  get
$$s_n(x)'=s_{n-1}(x),\ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ s_n'(x)=s_n(x)-{x^n\over n!}$$
Therefore $(-1)n!s_n(x)$ is a solution of $y'=y+x^n.$
Now combining all the above we obtain that the general solution of $y'=y+p(x)$ is equal
$$y=ce^x-\sum_{k=0}^nk!\,p_k s_k(x)$$